# search by date in oracle db by php

Tags: php, html, sql, select, oracle11g

My task is to create opportunities for users of my site to change interval dates to see the desired information from the Oracle database, but the problem is that when I'm changing something in the SQL select query in oracle goes wrong, can you give me some direction. i don't know what i must change ;; here is code

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>    
<form>
From:<input name="Date_1" type="Date" value="<%=Date_1%>" size="15" />
To:<input name="Date_2" type="Date" value="<%=Date_2%>" size="15" />
<input name="Submit" type="submit" />
</form>     
<?php
$conn = oci_connect('scott', 'tiger', '(DESCRIPTION= (ADDRESS= (PROTOCOL=) (HOST=) (PORT=)) (CONNECT_DATA= (SERVICE_NAME=)))');
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$sql = "SELECT * from somewhere WHERE name_date between '{$Date_1}' AND '{$Date_2}'";    
if (empty($_GET['name_date']))
$sql = "SELECT * FROM name_date WHERE 1 = 2 ";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
?>    
</body>
</html>
```

errors ;
Notice: Undefined variable: Date_1 on line 18;
Notice: Undefined variable: Date_2 on line 18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like your php code and sql needs to be in separate files. It looks like the same page containing the form also tries to make the sql connection before actually having the values for $Date_1 and $Date_2. If you looked at the query being sent to Oracle, the query is probably blank for those variables causing the error:

SELECT * from somewhere WHERE name_date between '' AND ''
group by TRUNC(a.CTS,'DD')
order by TRUNC(a.CTS,'DD')
 Instead you might want to try two files like this:

Part1.php:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>    
<form action="part2.php" method="post">
From:<input name="Date_1" type="Date" size="15" />
To:<input name="Date_2" type="Date"size="15" />
<input name="Submit" type="submit" />
</form>     
</body>
</html>
```

Part2.php

```
<?php
$Date_1 = $_POST['Date_1'];
$Date_2 = $_POST['Date_2'];
$conn = oci_connect('scott', 'tiger', '(DESCRIPTION= (ADDRESS= (PROTOCOL=) (HOST=) (PORT=))    (CONNECT_DATA= (SERVICE_NAME=)))');
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$sql = "SELECT * from somewhere WHERE name_date between '{$Date_1}' AND '{$Date_2}'
group by TRUNC(a.CTS,'DD')
order by TRUNC(a.CTS,'DD')";    
if (empty($_GET['name_date']))
$sql = "SELECT * FROM name_date WHERE 1 = 2 ";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, i've tried, and  have new errors ;;
Notice: Undefined index: Date_1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\part2.php on line 2

Notice: Undefined index: Date_2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\part2.php on line 3; do you know what's the problem?

Comment: yes sorry, you want $_POST['Date_1']; not $_GET. I updated the code above. Notice this is the same as the method in the html code. Also you must run part1.php first and have it properly redirect you to part2.php or you will get the error anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this happens because your variables are defined after the point where you're using them.

If you define a variable on the top of your code, it will be accessible to all the parts (if it has a value, of course) but if you define it on the bottom and use it before defining (which is kind of what you're doing) then the variable doesn't exist yet, remember: PHP runs line by line when executing.

To solve this problem cut and paste your entire PHP code:

```
<?php
 $conn = oci_connect('scott', 'tiger', '(DESCRIPTION= (ADDRESS= (PROTOCOL=) (HOST=) (PORT=))      (CONNECT_DATA= (SERVICE_NAME=)))');
 if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
 }
 //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 $sql = "SELECT * from somewhere WHERE name_date between '{$Date_1}' AND '{$Date_2}'";    
 if (empty($_GET['name_date']))
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM name_date WHERE 1 = 2 ";
 $res = mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

Right on top of your HTML Code.

Comment: This will not work, he isn't defining the variables in php to print into the html, he wants to use html to grab the variables and pass it to php.